# Обрезается фон сайта при малом размере окна

Tags: html, css, viewport

Возникла проблема с отображением фона сайта, если размер окна браузера меньше заданного размера. Допустим ширина сайта 1600px. Если я уменьшу ширину браузера до 1500px, то при скроле в бок, на месте фона будет просто пустота, будто его просто обрезали:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, "подстраивается" и заголовок. 
Для телефонов решение это установить минимальную ширину. Какое решение есть для десктопных браузеров?

Попробую описать подробнее. 
Использую bootstrap 4 c flexbox.

Код контейнера:

```
container-fixed
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 1600px;
}
```

В обшем-то копия из бутсрапа, только с заданной шириной.

Конструкция примерно следующая:

```
<container-fixed>
    <row>
        <block class="col-xs-12 headbg"></block>
    </row>
</container-fixed>
```

Тег `row` аналог класса `row`.

```
block {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; }
```

Фон задаю таким образом

```
.headbg
{
    background-image: url("..");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

section 
{ 
   width: 100%; 
   min-width: 100%; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: а что ты за сайт делаешь?

Comment: можно сделать ширину контейнера max-width: 1600px; width:100%

Comment: Как мы можем тебе помочь когда даже кода нету? Мы экстрасенсы что бы понять какой магией вы ограничили блок по размерам или что не продумали? Потрудитесь предоставить часть кода в которой имеется проблема. В конце концов часто проблему сами решают когда загружают код, просмотрев его повторно.

Comment: @FrankSinatra Да фигню всякую.

Comment: container-fixed
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    max-width: 1600px; width:100%
}
вот так пробуй

Comment: @FrankSinatra, `max-width: 1600px; width:100%` не подойдет ибо он просто ужимает сайт

Comment: так, а ты адаптивный сайт делаешь или нет?

Comment: @FrankSinatra, нет, фиксированный. Проблема в том, что сам сайт физически остаётся правильного размера, то есть нигде ничего не едет. Обрезается именно фон.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
вот такую штуку попробуй поставить в head

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46535/discussion-between-frank-sinatra-and-bwehaafox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section { 
    width: 1600px; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score -1):

1. Задавайте ширину не в пикселях, а в % (100% вместо 1600px).
2. Поместите всё в родительский блок и задайте ему 100% ширину. Дочерние задавайте в пикселях.